# "aus der Kita" oder "von der Kita" abholen

Tags: word-choice

Wie sagt ihr das, Muttersprachler?

> Ich hole mein Kind von der Kita ab.

oder

> Ich hole mein Kind aus der Kita ab.

Das gleiche würde ich noch für die Schule fragen für die Zukunft :)

> Aus der Schule abholen

vs.

> Von der Schule abholen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beides ist möglich, der Sinn ist jedoch ein bisschen verschieden: Mit *aus der Schule* referiert man auf das Schulgebäude, mit *von der Schule* referiert man auf die Institution Schule. Ganz analog gilt das für die Kita.

Was man sagt, kann situativ verschieden sein: Wenn man ausdrücken will, dass man das Kind "in die Freizeit" holt, dann scheint mir angebracht *von der Schule* zu verwenden, wenn man eher auf den Ort referieren will, dann scheint mir eher *aus der Schule* angebracht.

> Ich hole mein Kind von der Schule ab, und dann gehen wir in den Zoo.
>
> Ich hole mein Kind aus der Schule ab, nicht aus der Turnhalle.

In der Regel scheint man aber auf die Institution Schule referieren zu wollen, sodass sich *von der Schule* für mich "natürlicher", d.h. gewohnter, anhört.

Comment: Vielleicht hilft die Ergänzung: während viele Eltern ihre kleinen Kinder tatsächlich innerhalb der Kita abholen (-> „aus“), werden sie hoffentlich ihre Sprösslinge allenfalls vor der Schule in Empfang nehmen (-> „von“). Für Kitas sind daher beide Formulierungen gebräuchlich, je nach Kontext, der allgemeine Fall ist „von“.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn das Kind beim Abholen noch in der Schule ist, im Unterricht etwa, dann holst Du es aus der Schule ab, etwa wenn sich bei seinem Geschwister eine hochinfektiöse Krankheit gezeigt hat und zu befürchten ist, dass das andere Kind schon angesteckt ist.

Normalerweise holst Du das Kind von der Schule ab, weil Du sie nicht selbst betrittst, sondern davor wartest oder das Kind wartet davor.

Bei der Kita behütet man Kinder meist stärker, schon damit sie nicht auf die Straße laufen, so dass man in die Kita geht, um das Kind abzuholen, und sie deshalb aus der Kita abholt. "Von der Kita" ist aber nicht falsch.